# My django web app is holding on to old image data in memory. How can I clear it after every submit?

Tags: python, django, io, base64

I have built a django app that asks for user input, then uses `numpy` and `matplotlib.pyplot` to generate graphs and display them in my web page. I'm not saving the data to disk, but rather saving it to memory using `io` and `base64`, which may be part of the problem. On first submit, I get something like [this](https://gyazo.com/e688abab3f5cf007031bf69b6888324a), which is exactly what I want, but then on subsequent submits, I never get rid of the old graphs and end up with something like [this](https://gyazo.com/f276056e7068f169b639858ff52d4c07) and [this](https://gyazo.com/98c0ecbeb66a17e468e0125f829ace85).

Here is my views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import NNInput

import numexpr as ne
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import io
import base64
from PIL import Image
from .FeedForwardNN import FFNN

# Create your views here.


def ffnn(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NNInput(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            net = FFNN(1, 1, [cd['n'] for i in range(cd['m'])])
            x = np.arange(-1, 1, .001)
            x.shape = (x.shape[0], 1)
            untrained = net.evaluate(x)

            fig_untrained = plt.figure(1)
            plt.xlabel('x- axis')
            plt.ylabel('y-axis')
            plt.title('Pre-Training NN (green) vs function')
            y = ne.evaluate(cd['func'])
            plt.plot(x, y, 'r', x, untrained, 'g')

            buf = io.BytesIO()
            fig_untrained.savefig(buf, format='png')
            im = Image.open(buf)
            buf2 = io.BytesIO()
            im.save(buf2, format='png')
            im_str = base64.b64encode(buf2.getvalue()).decode()
            data_uri = 'data:image/png;base64,'
            data_uri += im_str
            context = dict()
            context['data1'] = data_uri

            epochs, history = net.train_mini_batches(x, y, .001, 200, .01)
            fig_loss = plt.figure(2)
            plt.xlabel('Epochs')
            plt.ylabel('Mean Squared Error')
            plt.title('Loss')
            plt.plot(epochs, history, 'b')
            
            buf3 = io.BytesIO()
            fig_loss.savefig(buf3, format='png')
            im2 = Image.open(buf3)
            buf4 = io.BytesIO()
            im2.save(buf4, format='png')
            im_str2 = base64.b64encode(buf4.getvalue()).decode()
            data_uri2 = 'data:image/png;base64,'
            data_uri2 += im_str2
            context['data2'] = data_uri2

            trained = net.evaluate(x)
            fig_trained = plt.figure(3)
            plt.xlabel('x-axis')
            plt.ylabel('y-axis')
            plt.title('Post-Training NN (green) vs function')
            plt.plot(x, y, 'r', x, trained, 'g')

            buf5 = io.BytesIO()
            fig_trained.savefig(buf5, format='png')
            im3 = Image.open(buf5)
            buf6 = io.BytesIO()
            im3.save(buf6, format='png')
            im_str3 = base64.b64encode(buf6.getvalue()).decode()
            data_uri3 = 'data:image/png;base64,'
            data_uri3 += im_str3
            context['data3'] = data_uri3

            return render(request, 'my_feedforward_nn/posttraining.html', context)
    else:
        form = NNInput(initial={'m':1, 'n':64, 'func':'(exp(-x)-exp(x))*x**3'})
        context = dict()
        context = {
            'form': form,
        }
        return render(request, 'my_feedforward_nn/feedforwarddefault.html', context)
```

Here is my posttraining.html file

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <img src={{ data1 }} alt="" height="250" ,width="250">
    <img src={{ data2 }} alt="" height="250" ,width="250">
    <img src={{ data3 }} alt="" height="250" ,width="250">
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some similar code in a different app that didn't have the same problem. It turns out the difference was in that code, each time I plotted a function, I called `plt.figure()` instead of `plt.figure(n)`, n being 1, 2, or 3. Changing to `plt.figure()` fixed my issue, but I am now wondering if all those figures that get opened hang around and could cause memory issues.